# Post value is in form empty

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a reservation form with input checks. If there is something filled in wrong, i want it to refill the reservation form again with the same values which were submitted. The form i use for this is :

```
<p class="contentreserverentekst cutcorners">Ook bieden wij u de mogelijkheid om te kunnen reserveren via het internet. Hiervoor hoeft u alleen maar een aantal gegevens in te vullen met betrekking tot de reservering. De reservering is pas vast nadat wij een bevestiging hebben verstuurd per mail.</p>
                    <form class="contentreserveren cutcorners" action="reserveren.php" method="POST" >
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="onlytext" id="naam">Voor- en achternaam:*</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="naam" id="naambox" value="<?$naam?>" size="40"></input></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="onlytext" id="personen">Aantal personen:*</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="personen" id="personenbox" value="<?$personen?>" size="40"></input></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="onlytext" id="datum">Datum:*</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="datum" id="datumbox" value="<?$datum?>" class='datepicker' size="40"></input></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="onlytext" id="tijd">Tijd:*</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="tijd" id="tijdbox" value="<?$tijd?>" size="40"></input></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="onlytext" id="telefoon">Telefoonnummer:*</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="telefoon" id="telefoonbox" value="<?$telefoon?>" size="40"></input></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="onlytext" id="email">E-Mail:*</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="email" id="emailbox" value="<?$email?>" size="40"></input></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="onlytext">Opmerkingen:</td>
                                <td><textarea cols="36" rows="7"  name="opmerking" value="<?$opmerking?>"></textarea></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" action="submit" value="Reserveer!" class="reservebutton"></input></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
```

After i click the button, the form sends me back to reserveren.php. In the beginning of the class i have :

```
<?php
$naam = $_POST["naam"];
$personen = $_POST["personen"];
$datum = $_POST["datum"];
$tijd = $_POST["tijd"];
$telefoon = $_POST["telefoon"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$opmerking = $_POST["opmerking"];

echo $naam;
echo $personen;
echo $datum;
echo $tijd;
echo $telefoon;
echo $email;
echo $opmerking;
?>
```

The page does echo all the right value's which were filled in the form, but the form inputs are empty.(I already put the value of the input right).

Could someone help me out?

Thanks, Sinan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not `echo` them, in short tags that is: `<?=$variables?>`, or go for the full `<?php echo $variable; ?>`.

---

As Dimitar Dimitrov correctly notes - I also discourage short tags. They require a setting enabled on your server and might cause problems with software upgrades or migrations.

Comment: I would suggest not using short tags.

Answer (score 0):

the variables need to be echoed

```
<p class="contentreserverentekst cutcorners">Ook bieden wij u de mogelijkheid om te kunnen reserveren via het internet. Hiervoor hoeft u alleen maar een aantal gegevens in te vullen met betrekking tot de reservering. De reservering is pas vast nadat wij een bevestiging hebben verstuurd per mail.</p>
                    <form class="contentreserveren cutcorners" action="reserveren.php" method="POST" >
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="onlytext" id="naam">Voor- en achternaam:*</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="naam" id="naambox" value="<? echo $naam;?>" size="40"></input></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="onlytext" id="personen">Aantal personen:*</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="personen" id="personenbox" value="<? echo $personen;?>" size="40"></input></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="onlytext" id="datum">Datum:*</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="datum" id="datumbox" value="<? echo $datum;?>" class='datepicker' size="40"></input></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="onlytext" id="tijd">Tijd:*</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="tijd" id="tijdbox" value="<? echo $tijd;?>" size="40"></input></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="onlytext" id="telefoon">Telefoonnummer:*</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="telefoon" id="telefoonbox" value="<? echo $telefoon;?>" size="40"></input></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="onlytext" id="email">E-Mail:*</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="email" id="emailbox" value="<? echo $email;?>" size="40"></input></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="onlytext">Opmerkingen:</td>
                                <td><textarea cols="36" rows="7"  name="opmerking" value="<? echo $opmerking;?>"></textarea></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" action="submit" value="Reserveer!" class="reservebutton"></input></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
```